# Redis module : calling dump command in module return nothing

Tags: c, redis

I develop a redis module that call the native redis `DUMP` command.
But when i call dump command on existing key, nothing is return but if i replace the `DUMP` command by `GET` the value is returned

Here is the code :

```
#include "redismodule.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mydump_command(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {
  REDISMODULE_NOT_USED(argc);
  RedisModule_AutoMemory(ctx);

  RedisModuleCallReply *rep = RedisModule_Call(ctx, "DUMP", "s", argv[1]);

  const char *value = RedisModule_CallReplyStringPtr(rep, NULL);

  RedisModule_Log(ctx, "warning", value);

  RedisModule_ReplyWithSimpleString(ctx, value);
  return REDISMODULE_OK;
}

int myget_command(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {
  REDISMODULE_NOT_USED(argc);
  RedisModule_AutoMemory(ctx);

  RedisModuleCallReply *rep = RedisModule_Call(ctx, "GET", "s", argv[1]);

  const char *value = RedisModule_CallReplyStringPtr(rep, NULL);

  RedisModule_Log(ctx, "warning", value);

  RedisModule_ReplyWithSimpleString(ctx, value);
  return REDISMODULE_OK;
}

int RedisModule_OnLoad(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {

  if (RedisModule_Init(ctx, "module_test", 1, REDISMODULE_APIVER_1) == REDISMODULE_ERR) {
    return REDISMODULE_ERR;
  }

  if (RedisModule_CreateCommand(ctx, "mydump", mydump_command, "write deny-oom", 1, 1, 1) == REDISMODULE_ERR) {
    return REDISMODULE_ERR;
  }

  if (RedisModule_CreateCommand(ctx, "myget", myget_command, "write deny-oom", 1, 1, 1) == REDISMODULE_ERR) {
    return REDISMODULE_ERR;
  }

  return REDISMODULE_OK;
}
```

In redis-cli i get the following result :

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET foo bar
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET foo
"bar"
127.0.0.1:6379> DUMP foo
"\x00\x03bar\b\x00_\x93\xa5\xdfG\x7fw/"
127.0.0.1:6379> mydump foo

127.0.0.1:6379> myget foo
bar
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Note that with my custom command, redis-cli don't disply double quotes.

Can someone help me know why calling `DUMP` command return nothing.

Comment: Can't you provide some [MCVE] that we could test on our systems? Please **edit your question** to improve it, so give us your `main` function...

Comment: Of course. But i can provide only the module code.

Comment: Then show the command loading that module, and perhaps a sample REDIS data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're treating the reply as a simple string, whereas Redis' may be binary. While `GET` returns a simple string value (as you `SET foo bar`), `DUMP`s encoding is binary. The following works:

```
int mydump_command(RedisModuleCtx *ctx, RedisModuleString **argv, int argc) {
  REDISMODULE_NOT_USED(argc);
  RedisModule_AutoMemory(ctx);

  RedisModuleCallReply *rep = RedisModule_Call(ctx, "DUMP", "s", argv[1]);

  size_t vlen;
  const char *value = RedisModule_CallReplyStringPtr(rep, &vlen);

  RedisModule_ReplyWithStringBuffer(ctx, value, vlen);
  return REDISMODULE_OK;
}
```

Comment: You're most welcome :) Note that your existing `myget` **will fail** in the same way for a binary string (i.e. not "bar")